# 415 - Unsupported Media Type

Tags: angularjs

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

import { Event, SearchParameters } from './event.model';

@Injectable()
export class EventService {    
    private _url = "http://localhost:36888/api/HealthFairEvents";

    constructor(private _http: Http) {

    }

    getEvents(SearchParameters) {        
        return this._http.post(this._url + "/HealthFairEventSL", SearchParameters).map(res => res.json());
    }

    getEvent(id: number) {        
        return this._http.get(this._url + "/GetHealthFairEvent/" + id).map(res => res.json());
    }

    addEvent(event: any){
        console.log('add');
        console.log(JSON.stringify(event));
        return this._http.post(this._url + "/PostHealthFairEvent", JSON.stringify(event)).map(res => res.json());
    }

    updateEvent(event: Event){
        console.log('update');        
        console.log(JSON.stringify(event));
        return this._http.put(this._url + "/PutHealthFairEvent/" + event.HealthFairEventId, JSON.stringify(event), 

        ).map(res => res.json());
    }
}
```

it look like I need to send the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*' or CORS with the _http request. but I am not able to do it. I checked the Angular4 documentation but no success. Please help me thanks.

Comment: This is a backend issue.   Are you using .NET?

Comment: Yes. I am using Web API which is on .Net based. CORS is enabled on WEB API side? my problem is how to send allow origin from http object from angular side.

Answer (score 0):

CORS happens on the server side and the only headers necessary on the client side is the content type.

Example:

```
import { Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';

getEvent(id: number) {
        let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
        return this._http.get(this._url + "/GetHealthFairEvent/" + id, options).map(res => res.json());
    }
```

On the server side, to enable CORS there are several ways to do this.   The easiest is to add this to your web.config *after* [installing the Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors package from NuGet.](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors)

```
  <system.webServer>
   <httpProtocol>
     <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="http://localhost:4200" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="*" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" value="true" />
     </customHeaders>
   </httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>
```

More detailed information about CORS from Microsoft: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api

Answer (score 0):

Correct answer is,

```
updateEvent(event: HealthFairEvent){
        console.log('update');        
        console.log(JSON.stringify(event));
        let customHeader = new Headers();
        customHeader.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');

        return this._http.put(this._url + "/XX/" + event.HealthFairEventId, event, { headers: customHeader } ).map(res => res.json());        
    }
```